# ReplaceAll on a Plot - Can you reproduce this error?

Tags: replacement

[image]

The weird thing is that it occurs only the first time I evaluate it!
The same happens with `Plot` but not with `Graphics`.

I can reproduce this on Mathematica 11.3 and Wolfram Engine 12 (wolframscript) on Linux Debian 9 (Stretch).

Comment: The error seems to come from `Method -> {"CoordinatesToolOptions" -> {"DisplayFunction" -> \
({(Identity[#1] &)[#1[[1]]], (Identity[#1] &)[#1[[2]]]} &)` but still,  weird that it happens only at the first evaluation

Comment: This is due to the fact that the pattern `_?NumericQ` causes `NumericQ` to be applied to all the parts of the graphics expression. One of them is the body of the `"DisplayFunction"`, which contains `#1[[2]]` (which is not wrapped in `Function[...]`, since we're only looking at the body of the function now). This causes the error you observe, but I'm not entirely sure why it only happens once. Presumably, `ReplaceAll` does some caching somewhere. One way around this is to use ``_?System`Dump`HeldNumericQ`` instead. This function prevents its argument from evaluating, so the issue does not occur

Comment: I was able to reproduce with v12.0.0.0 on macOS Catalina 10.15